# how do i print a value of a document in pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, output, pymongo

ok suppose a doc looks like this:

```
{
    _id: ObjectId("63623815660b1cbf9d151a55"),
    name: 'Charmander',
    pokedex_id: '004',
    type: 'Fire',
    stats: [ { health: 10 }, { power: 15 }, { defense: 7 } ],
    moves: [ 'ember', 'growl', 'n/a', 'n/a' ]
  }
```

i want to get only the name element of the document to store in a variable in pymongo
this is the code i am using

```
pokemon_python = client.pokemon_python
gonestarter = pokemon_python.gonestarter

char_name = gonestarter.find_one({"stats":{"$elemMatch":{"health": 10}}}, {"name"})
print(str(char_name))
```

the output is:
{'_id': ObjectId('63623815660b1cbf9d151a55'), 'name': 'Charmander'}

but the desired output i want is that it prints only Charmander:
Charmander

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
  print(str(char_name['name']))
```